# How do I make xmacro in ubuntu playback at the same speed

Tags: scripts

I found a user stating

> You can use X-Macro.
>
> To install x-Macro use this command:
>
> `sudo apt-get install xmacro`
>
> For record use `xmacrorec2` command:
>
> `xmacrorec2 > test.file`
>
> for play recorded macro use `xmacroplay`
>
> `xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < test.file`

But when I run it it plays it back very fast I would like it to play back at the same speed. Also how would I be able to play it back a certian number of times?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can adjust delay parameter ("delay in milliseconds for events sent to remote display", it is defaulted to 10 ms), but you can increase this value to 100:

```bsh
xmacroplay -d 100 "$DISPLAY" < test.file
```

See `xmacroplay -h` for details.